# Are monotonic and bijective functions the same?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

The question is simple :  consider the family of **monotonic functions** ; $m(x) : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and the familly of **bijective functions** ; $b(x) : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  Are they actually the same?  If not, I would like to see some simple counter-examples.

Comment: $f(x)=1$ is monotonous but not bijective

Comment: Nitpick: You should be saying "monotone" or "monotonic", not "monotonous".

Comment: @MPW: Agreed. Hence my edit to the question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Short answer:

$f(x)=1$

is monotonic, but clearly not bijective.

---

Longer answer:

You are probably asking about *strictly* monotonic functions (that way you can get injectivity), but the answer is still *no*.

$f(x)=e^x$ is monotonic, but not bijective.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x & x>0\lor x<-1\\ -x-1 & -1\leq x\leq 0\end{cases}$$

is bijective, but not monotonic.

---

Even longer answer:

You might mean *strictly monotonic continuous* functions, in which case the answer is still no ($f(x)=e^x$ is strictly monotonic and continuous, but not bijective), however, it is true that the other type of counterexample cannot be found, i.e.

> Every continuous bijective function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ is strictly monotonic.

---

**Edit for the question posed in comments**:

You are making a mistake a lot of math students make, and it's usually the fault of the teachers not emphasizing it enough. The thing is:

***A FUNCTION IS DEFINED BY THREE THINGS***:

1. The domain.
2. The codomain.
3. The "action".

So, if I want to **truly** mathematically correctly define some function, I can say:

> $f$ is the function **from** $A$ to $B$ defined by $f(x)=...$

Note, it is important to note both **from where** the function is mapping, **to where** it is mapping, and **how** it is mapping.

Example:

- The function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=e^x$ is a function.
- The function $g:\mathbb R\to(0,\infty)$ defined by $g(x)=e^x$ is a function.

**IMPORTANT**:

$f$ and $g$ **are not the same function**. I cannot stress this enough. $f$ and $g$ map all numbers to the exact same number, but because their codomains are different, they are, by definition, different functions. It is true that if we *restrict* the codomain of $f$ to $(0,\infty)$, we get $g$, but it is not true that $f$ is the same function as $g$.

**Why**?

You may think this is unnecessary, but it is very necessary if you want any meaningful definition of the word **surjective**. Why? Well, remember:

> A function $f:A\to B$ is surjective if, for every $b\in B$, there exists some $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$.

Now, take any function $h:A\to B$. And define $B'=f(A)=\{f(a)|a\in A\}$. Then, this statement is true:

- For every $b\in B'$, there exists some $a\in A$ such that $h(a)=b$.

So, is $h$ all of a sudden surjective? Just because we restricted its codomain? **NO**. If we restrict $h$ to $B'$, we get a different function, and the *restricted* function is surjective, but $h$ may not be.

Similarly, our function $g$ mapping from $\mathbb R$ to $(0,\infty)$ is surjective, but the function $f$ is not.

Comment: why is it not bijective. explanation please.

Comment: It stays positive. ($0$, and any negative number, is not in the image)

Comment: @A.Molendijk Because there exists no $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=-1$.

Comment: iknow but it is not clear w.r.t the OP.

Comment: The sentence "Every continuous bijective function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is strictly monotonous." is interesting.  Can it be reverted, as "Every continuous strictly monotonous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is bijective." ?

Comment: @Cham Did you even read my answer? Read the part in parentheses of the last paragraph...

Comment: @5xum, hmm it's not totally clear to me yet.  You have $y = e^x$, as a mapping from A to B, and it can be inverted :  $x = \ln{y}$, which is a mapping of B to A.  For each value of $x \in A$, there is a unique value of $y \in B$.  But also, for each value of $y \in B$, there is a unique value of $x \in A$, so the mapping is bijective, isn't ?

Comment: @Cham No, $y=e^x$ is a mapping from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, and when you take $\mathbb R$ as the codomain, the function is **not** bijective. There is **no** value $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=-1$, therefore the function is not surjective.

Comment: @Cham The function **is** a bijective function from $\mathbb R$ to $(0,\infty)$, but that's a different function (because it has a different codomain).

Comment: @5xum, if $B \equiv \mathbb{R}$, yes I agree.  But I think this is too restrictive.  I'm not convinced yet.

Comment: @Cham I added a detailed explanation in my answer. Please read through it and tell me if it is clear now.

Comment: @5xum, thanks for your edit.  I'll be back later today since I need to go now.

Comment: @5xum "...but because their domains are different...". I presume "codomain" is meant here.

Comment: Nice explain (+1)

Comment: My book says `Every continuous Real function on a closed Interval is bijective `  <--- is this true? I found it here https://waa.ai/fgD2

Comment: @john It is absolutely not true. The constant function is a counterexample.

Comment: @john Also, if you read your source carefully, what it says is Every real funciton on a closed interval is bijective IF AND ONLY IF it is strictly monotic. That's a completely different statement!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the zero function. It is monotonous yet not injective, since if $x_1 \neq x_2$ does not imply that $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you really mean strictly monotone functions, since constant functions are monotone and obviously not bijective. But even so, it is not enough. (Recall: a function $f:X\to Y$ between topological spaces is said to be monotone if $f^{-1}(y)$ is connnected for each $y\in Y$. Monotone functions can have "flat" spots where they are locally constant.)

It's a simple matter to construct a large number of nonbijective monotone functions.
If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is monotone, then $E_f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, where $E_f(x)\equiv e^{f(x)}$, is a monotone function which is not surjective (so not bijective).

Comment: Merry christmas :)